# How do I use a .pem file to make get requests to the Google Shopping API in .net

Tags: .net, google-api, pem

I've been tasked with retrieving data feeds from a merchant center account. I've been given a .pem file and some sample code for making requests in JavaScript... But I've been asked to deliver a C# solution and I'm struggling.

I specifically want to make a request to https://www.googleapis.com/content/V2/[merchantId]/datafeedstatuses

I have the merchantId and understand the scope. I think I understand conceptually how an oauth 2.0 request works (though I've made an oauth 2.0 request before)... But I just cannot find any sample code for how you may use a pem file to make one of these requests.

If anyone can give me somewhere to start I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used the Shopping API from Google. I worked with emails, directory, people apis. It is not easy. I checked Google has nuget packages for their shopping APIs. The one you, probably, need is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2/. Here is some code I have that you might be able to adopt for your needs:

```
var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(GoogleSettings.ClientEmail)
{
    Scopes = GoogleSettings.Scopes,
    User = GoogleSettings.AdminAccount,
};
var initFromCert = initializer.FromPrivateKey(GoogleSettings.PrivateKey);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initFromCert);
```

and then for directory service I used

```
var directoryService = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = GoogleSettings.ProjectID,
            });
```

All the `GoogleSettings` are collected from the JSON downloaded from Google project setup. In you case the pem file should contain the private key that could be extracted. Or you need to get it otherwise.